# How to get other documents' data by document id in map function

Tags: join, view, couchdb

I have a problem "joining" some documents in a view. Here's my schema: Documents with type "category" can hold an embedded array of ids to documents with type "page". Both have a field "name".

My Documents:

```
{
   "_id": "887c28dcf6dd8429d404d276b900b203",
   "_rev": "3-c4d1e0c8378bb0081b5fe3522ee649a0",
   "TYPE": "category",
   "NAME": "Home",
   "PAGES": [
       {"PAGE_ID": "887c28dcf6dd8429d404d276b900ad8f"},
       {"PAGE_ID": "887c28dcf6dd8429d404d276b900b203"},
       {"PAGE_ID": "887c28dcf6dd8429d404d276b900bae0"}
   ]
}

{
   "_id": "887c28dcf6dd8429d404d276b9008c01",
   "_rev": "1-afd54c654ae5afa56a3fbd7b1ba119d2",
   "TYPE": "page",
   "NAME": "Foo"
}
```

Now I want to join these in a view with this map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.TYPE == "category") {
    for (id in doc.PAGES) {
      emit(doc.NAME, doc.PAGES[id].PAGE_ID);
    }
  }
}
```

But instead of the PAGE_ID I want the NAME of the referencing document.
This is basically [the example from the CouchDB wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EntityRelationship#One_to_Many:_Embedded_Documents), but they don't show the map function. So any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a `_id` field somewhere in your output value. After that, you use `include_docs=true` and the view will include the linked document instead of the source document. For example:

```
function(doc) {
   if (doc.TYPE == "category") {
      for (var x = 0; x < doc.PAGES.length; x++) {
         emit(doc.NAME, { _id: doc.PAGES[x].PAGE_ID });
      }
   }
}
```

When you query this view, you add `include_docs=true` to your URL. And your view output will add a new field to each row called `doc`. Ordinarily, that field will contain the full source document. In this case, it will include the linked document you are referring to.

**EDIT** Btw, you're using the `for...in` loop incorrectly. A `for...in` is used to loop over the properties of an object. You need to use a simple `for` loop to iterate an array like this.

Comment: Hi, now I get a weird result: The first page of the list gets resolved then I get two categories with the unresolved page ids and then the fourth page (resolved again). But I have two categories (first contains three pages, second just one) and four pages.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that your 2nd `PAGE_ID` is the same as `_id` for the document itself. Oh, and I just noticed your JS is wrong... (watch out for a change to my answer)

Comment: Oh, I made a stupid copy'n'paste mistake with the IDs, sorry for that. Now it works, Thank You!

Comment: Also consider including a `_rev` field so when you `?include_docs=true` you will get the actual document that corresponded to that map output. (Or if you don't use include_docs, you still now the revision so you can update the document without re-fetching it.)