# Embed different entities one to another

Tags: couchdb

I have two types of documents (entities) "book" and "author".

Sample of book document:
{
  _id:"123456",
  name:"Peace and War",
  pages:"2234",
  author_id:34567
}

Sample of author document:
{
  _id:"34567",
  surname:"Tolstoy",
  name:"Leo"
}

The question is: how could I create view which return me following structure:

{
  _id:"123456",
  name:"Peace and War",
  pages:"2234",
  author_id:34567,
  surname:"Tolstoy",
  name:"Leo"
}

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this maybe what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055450/couchdb-map-function-how-to-get-anothers-document-data-by-document-id

Comment: No, that's not. It'll return a whole author document as value with book's _id. But all other book's fields will not exist in this views.

Comment: @Integral WPCoder's link is correct. You can then use lists (use search) to "merge" the data into one object.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use WPCoder's idea with `include_docs=true` query to get response: `"value": { book_id:"123456", name:"Peace and War", pages:"2234" }, "doc": {_id:34567, surname:"Tolstoy", name:"Leo" }`. I would do that.

If you really do not like `include_docs` you can also try map:

```
if (doc.author_id) {
  emit([doc.author_id, doc._id], doc);
} else
// check if author
if (doc.surname && doc.name) {
  emit([_id, 0], doc);
}
```

Now the query with options `?startkey=["author id"]&endkey["author id", {}]` will return the list of books by the author. You can filter your book and merge it into a single object with list but you have to know the author a priori (search with the key not the author).

You can also use `keys=[["author id", 0], ["author id", "book id"]]` but you have to know both author and book id. It all depends what do you need it for. I repeat again: I would use what WPCoder suggested.

Comment: Well! Think I need to explain my question. The question isn't about how could I query two documents to receive another document.
The question is how can I receive such structure with many document, so I have 10 books and 3 authors and want to receive one json file with documents of only one new structure:

Comment: { _id:"123456", name:"Peace and War", pages:"2234", author_id:34567, surname:"Tolstoy", name:"Leo" },  
{ _id:"34567", name:"resurrection", pages:"331", author_id:34567, surname:"Tolstoy", name:"Leo" },  
{ _id:"4578", name:"Crime and Punishment", pages:"876", author_id:34568, surname:"Dostoevsky", name:"Fedor" }  
Without other documents. So next I could get this structure with Backbone js and define model.

Comment: I understand you question and the answer depends on what are your constraints on the knowledge of what you are searching for and the form of the result. If you allow to get the JSON `{..., value: {...the book data...}, doc: {...the author data...}}`, then the WPCoder's suggestion is your solution. It does require the knowledge of the book id. If you know the author id you can use also the other solution, which is more flexible with respect to the form of output you are reading (but does require greater a priori knowledge about the result).

Comment: Okay, the correct answer from WPCoder's suggestion is:
`map: function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "book"){
    emit(doc._id, {_id:doc.author, name: doc.name, pages: doc.pages});
  }
}`
But could you please tell me more about these words "You can filter your book and merge it into a single object with list but you have to know the author a priori..."?
Could you give an example (e.g. merging into a single object, list function)?
Many thanks!

Comment: Here is very useful reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084741/merge-view-collation-into-useful-output-in-couchdb